# Объясните причину баги в моем коде при работе со ссылками и указателями

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, коллекции

Недавно мой друг прислал мне кусок своего кода, нас тут по лабораторным просят писать свои коллекции, так что речь пойдет о собственноручной работе с памятью. Вообщем здесь кусок его заголовочного файла с коллекцией.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

struct Point {
    double x, y;
    Point() { x = 0; y = 0; }
};

namespace Data {
template<typename T>
class Array {
private:
    T *arrayPtr;                // Указатель на массив
    unsigned int count;         // Размер массива
public:
    Array<T>();                 // Конструктор
    Array<T>(int);              // Объявление и инициализация
    Array<T>(const Array<T>&);  // Конструктор копирования
    void Add(T);                // Добавить в конец
    void Clear();               // Очистить
    void Allocate(int);         // Изменить размер
    ~Array() { delete[] arrayPtr; } // Деструктор       
    unsigned int size() const { return count; }     // Количество элементов
    // Операторы
    Array& operator=(const Array&);                 // Присваивание
    T& operator[] (unsigned int) const;             // Индексация
    T& operator[] (int) const;                      // Индексация
};

// Копирующий конструктор
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array<T>& arr) {
    count = arr.count;
    Allocate(count);
    //arrayPtr = new T[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        this->arrayPtr[i] = arr.arrayPtr[i];
    }
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>&        
Array<T>::operator=(const Array<T>& arr) {
    if(this != &arr) {                              // Чтобы избежать присваивания самому себе
        this->count = arr.count;
        Allocate(count);
        //if (this->arrayPtr != arr.arrayPtr) {     // Если новый массив - не модифицированный старый
        //  if (arrayPtr) { delete[] arrayPtr; }    // Удаляем указатель на старый
        //}
        //arrayPtr = new T[this->count];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->count; i++) {
            this->arrayPtr[i] = arr.arrayPtr[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](unsigned int i) const {
    // Если вышли за пределы массива - выдаём exception
    return (i < this->count) ? arrayPtr[i] : throw std::out_of_range("Array index out of range");
}

template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](int i) const {
    // Если вышли за пределы массива - выдаём exception
    return ((i < this->count) && (i >= 0)) ? arrayPtr[i] : throw std::out_of_range("Array index out of range");
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array() {
    this->count = 0;
    arrayPtr = new T[count];
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int size) {
    this->count = size;
    arrayPtr = new T[this->count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->count; i++)
    {
        arrayPtr[i] = T;
    }
}

// Изменение размера
template <typename T>
void Array<T>::Allocate(int newSize) {      
    T *temp = new T[newSize];               // Создаём новый массив
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        if (i < this->count) {              // Пока есть элементы - копируем в новый массив
            temp[i] = this->arrayPtr[i];
        }
        else {                              // Начались новые элементы
            temp[i] = T();                  // Заполняем пустыми
        }
    }
    delete[] this->arrayPtr;                // Удаляем старый массив
    this->arrayPtr = temp;                  // Сохраняем новый
    this->count = newSize;                  // Сохраняем размер
}

// Добавление элемента в конец
template <typename T>
void Array<T>::Add(T value) {
    unsigned int temp = this->count + 1;        // Сохранили значение увеличенного на 1 массива
    Allocate(temp);                             // Увеличили массив на 1
    this->count = temp;                         // Сохранили размер массива
    this->arrayPtr[this->count - 1] = value;    // Запомнили добавленный элемент
}

// Очистка
template <typename T>
void Array<T>::Clear() {
    this->count = 0;
    Allocate(this->count);
}

Array<Point> SortPoints(Array<Point> vectorPoints);
Array<Point> GeneratePoints(int);
//std::vector<Point> SortPoints(std::vector<Point> vectorPoints);
}
```

А здесь код, которым он ее тестировал

```
#include <iostream>
#include "data.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Point point;
point.x = 5;
point.y = 3;
Data::Array<Point> userPoints;
userPoints.Add(point);
point.x = 7;
point.y = 9;
userPoints.Add(point);
cout << userPoints[0].x << " " << userPoints[0].y<<"\n";
cout << userPoints[1].x << " " << userPoints[1].y << "\n";
Point dump = userPoints[0];
userPoints[0] = userPoints[1];
userPoints[1] = dump;
cout << userPoints[0].x << " " << userPoints[0].y << "\n";
cout << userPoints[1].x << " " << userPoints[1].y << "\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Я понимаю, что постоянное увеличение размера на единичку - ужасный ход, проще хранить отдельно количество выделенной под массив памяти и количество элементов, чтобы потом изредка увеличивать размер массива. Но речь не об этом. Речь о том, что выдает на консоль этот код, а именно

```
5 3
7 9
5 3
7 9
```

Лично я не смог найти причины для подобных результатов, но я определенно что-то упускаю, может кто-то из вас сможет дать этому объяснение? было бы интересно узнать причину

P.S. Пожалуйста, не стоит указывать решение проблемы, интересует причина проблемы, а не как ее исправить )

Comment: Могу поспорить, где-нибудь UB. Код не читал.

Comment: Visual Studio тоже выдаёт предупреждение, так что это надо просто их сознательно игнорировать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что проблема в тернарном операторе. Тернарный оператор возвращает r-value, и ссылка, возвращаемая из метода, указывает именно на временную переменную с этим r-value, а не на элемент массива.

PS по коду:

1. зачем присваивать `count` до или после вызова `Allocate`, если `Allocate` сам присваивает полю `count` новое значение?
2. сигнатура индексаторов - странная. Обычно в коллекциях константная перегрузка индексатора возвращает константную ссылку, а неконстантная перегрузка - обычную ссылку. Потому что когда кто-нибудь пишет `const Data::Array<Point>` - он ожидает полной неизменности массива.
3. `Allocate` приведет к утечкам памяти если код в цикле выкинет исключение
4. В методе `Allocate` присваивание `temp[i] = T()` излишние для всех типов кроме примитивных - его сделает `new`

Comment: Точно! Надо было не понтоваться, а писать с if'ом. Как раз обнаружил это в отладчике.

Comment: Кроме того, const-метод просто не может выдавать наружу не-const-ссылку на поле.

Comment: И это, кстати, было в ворнигах.

Comment: @VladD *"Кроме того, const-метод просто не может выдавать наружу не-const-ссылку на поле."* А `arrayPtr[i]` - это и не поле. Сам `arrayPtr` в этом методе - да, константный указатель. Но тот блок памяти, на который он ссылается - вполне себе изменяемый.

Comment: Хм, похоже, что да. Тогда просто семантика `const` реализована неверно: нельзя возвращать внутренности класса из const-метода доступными на запись.

Comment: А в 4 вы предлагаете при помощи TMP выяснить, примитивный ли тип T? Тогда проще написать `T *temp = new T[newSize]()` и получить value initialization.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov вы оказались правы, действительно дело в этом. Зря правда поменяли название вопроса, код ведь и впрямь не мой. Хотя предыдущее название было менее информативное. Никогда не слышал про r-value как результат тернарного оператора, откуда вычитали?